# How to produce a React component from .tsx files?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

At [How to insert a React component into a non-React HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65478153/856090) there is a question of how to embed a React component to a non-React HTML page. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) is a solution.

Continuing that issue: `react-scripts build` creates `.js` files with random names from `.tsx` files.

So, I cant use [the advice](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) to embed my React component into another page, because I don't know the file names to be used with my `<script>` tag in that HTML page.

So, what are alternative ways to do this (create `.js` files from `.tsx` and put where appropriate all other related files like images and CSS for my React component to be usable)?

I reported a [feature request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10308) for a way to do this, but it is not yet fulfilled, so please advise me for an alternative way to do.

Comment: Instead of using create-react-app, use [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) and build and compile your component using it.

Comment: @Adam Should `create-react-library` be called from the package that uses my component or directly from the package with the component? If from the the package with the component, then how to make it run from the calling package?

Comment: It’s just a means to compile your component. The only thing you really want to do is build an output anyway, you don’t even need that tool and could just use babel to output a bundle yourself, depending on how complex the component your building is

Comment: @Adam Excuse me, you haven't answered my question where `create-react-library` is advised to be called from.

Comment: How to use _both_ `create-react-app` and `create-react-library` for a single package with a React app? (I want my package to both be able to create a complete React app and a component to be used from other packages.)

Comment: I have answered your question, but you’ve failed to understand my answer. That’s ok, just don’t call me out for not answering when I have answered. You need to compile your component into an output .js file and then follow the directions in the react documentation on your other post about how to put a react component into a non react website

Comment: We stumbled on something similar and had a theory that next.js could solve this. We never tried but hopefully this you can understand: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering.

Comment: FYI, the process we were following was to wrap those components again in similar name individual components and use renderToString (passing component, required js and css in it again!). It was too much but yup we did it as we didn't find any good solution at that time. We still doing this and thinking to move to nextjs in future.

Comment: @Mr_Green I see no way how `next.js` would help to solve my problem that I described in the question.

Comment: @Mr_Green I do not understand what you suggest to do with the result of `renderToString` and how this result could be useful.

Comment: Each react component should have their own JS and css (modularization). You can't use the bundled JS in html files that will be too large(at least that was what our case was). Later we again copy pasted this JS and css code in another similar components package where we ran renderToString globally so html files with JS and css is generated. This again we embedded into HTML using gulp or dynamically calling those changes.

Comment: @Mr_Green So, you use copy&paste?! That's not a good idea usually. I want the task to be automated.

Comment: yes, I agree. that is where we discussed to include nextjs. I don't have a better understanding of how this will solve it but this is still in early discussions and many devs here are pressing to use this which I am not fully aware of. Give it a try maybe by going the above link. Might be helpful.